# SQL WHERE statement in SELECT?

Tags: sql, database, group-by, count, pivot

So I'm trying to output 2 columns that call on the same feature. Except 1 column I want the count of values less than 5 and another column I want count of values greater than 5.

```
SELECT COUNT (col_a) FROM table WHERE col_a < 5
```

is how you get the first.

But I'm wondering how to combine the 2 queries. Something like:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(col_a WHERE col_a < 5) AS col_1, 
    COUNT(col_a WHERE col_a > 5) AS col_2 
FROM table
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM table
    WHERE col_a < 5
)
, (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM table
    WHERE col_a < 5
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
     SUM(CASE WHEN col_a < 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS col_1, 
     SUM(CASE WHEN col_a > 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS col_2 
FROM mytable
```

Depending on your database, there may be neater options available. For databases that support the standard `FILTER` clause to aggregate functions (such as Postgres):

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE col_a < 5) AS col_1, 
     COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE col_a > 5) AS col_2 
FROM mytable
```

In MySQL:

```
SELECT 
     SUM(col_a < 5) AS col_1, 
     SUM(col_a > 5) AS col_2 
FROM mytable
```